# How to select music file from Apple music library using Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, file

I'm using `FilePicker` Flutter package to select files from Apple Music library as shown by following code snippet.

```
FilePickerResult? result =
        await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.audio);
```

It opens the library but it gives the following error when it tries to load the file.

`Entitlements] MSVEntitlementUtilities - Process Runner PID[57262] - Group: (null) - Entitlement: com.apple.accounts.appleaccount.fullaccess - Entitled: NO - Error: (null) [core] Attempted to register account monitor for types client is not authorized to access: {( "com.apple.account.iTunesStore" )}`

I have the Music App on my iPad but I don't have a subscription for Apple Music. Do I need a subscription to read a local music in Music App library?